# Encrypting multiple drives on a multi-boot system

Tags: encryption, cryptography, disk-encryption

So I am building a new [system](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/KKjJrH) and I want to *fully* encrypt it, problem is I am not really sure how since I never encrypted anything bigger than a folder or zip. The build includes a **Samsung 850 EVO-Series 500GB SSD** w/ self encryption for holding boot partitions and selected games/programs for quick loading; it also includes a **Western Digital BLACK SERIES 2TB HDD** for all my other data.

The OS that I will install are: **OSX El Capitan**, **Windows 10**, and **Arch Linux** in that order. (Also possibly Fedora and LFS.)

I'd appreciate some help on teaching me, advice, or steps on how to complete this.

I did do research, but I didn't find anything that would help. 
So inb4 LMGTFU.

Answer (score 0):

Natively Windows 10 uses bit locker for whole disk encryption.  OS X uses FileVault.  Archlinux will use dmcrypt or ecryptfs.  Each OS is incompatible with the other OS's encryption.  TrueCrypt used to be able to work cross platform, but it has been out of production since May of 2014.  There isn't anything natively that is compatible with all three systems.  So the only answer I am aware of is, "can't be done."

You can put each OS on it's own partition and encrypt it.  But then you can't get access to the partition from any of the other OS's.
If you aren't planning on using the system for gaming, I'd use OS X as my primary OS, run a type 2 hypervisor (VMWare, Parallels) and run the other OS's virtually.  Then encrypt the primary OS (OS X you'd use Filevault) and the whole disk is encrypted.

Comment: I've decided to install Windows and Arch, then put OSX on a VM. I am not too keen on using Microsoft's Bitlocker tbh. My partition table will probably look something like this:

/dev/sda1 fat32        EFI

/dev/sda2 NTFS       Games/other
/dev/sdb1 NTFS       Games/data
/dev/sdb2 EXT4       /
/dev/sdb3 EXT4       /home
/dev/sdb4 linux-swap swap

Comment: So maybe it's time to mark this question answered?

Comment: I was waiting for a second opinion.

Comment: Stack exchange isn't an "opinion" place.  Opinion questions are closed when asked.  You asked a question, and you have been provided the correct answer (there is no whole disk encryption that is cross platform compatible).  If you want other work arounds (like I provided, and like you said you used) you need to ask for that in a separate question.